# Tiling the view of the player camera in meta Quest 2 after updating version of unity and oculus integration

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I updated Unity from 2020.3.12 to 2021.3.27 and also updated the Oculus integration from version 36 to 54. I created a new stationary player for the menu scene and the camera works without problems. However, the player I created for the multiplayer scene gives me a tiled view for some unknown reason, as you can see in the image. It happens even when there is only one player in the multiplayer scene. The OVR Camera Rig is set up the same way in both players. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Screenshot from Meta Quest 2  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxCtw.jpg)

Screenshot OVR CAmera Rig  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMdfu.png)

I tried setting the rect viewport but the current setting seems to be correct. I have no idea what it could be.

Central Camera settings(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz6Jt.png)

Comment: Found a solution? Experiencing exactly the same. Scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Looks like normal android assets doesn't work in Oculus. I fixed it by going to the oculus option in player settings and applying all the recommended changes. Ran it and it worked as expected.